# Linq creating error in Internet Explorer only

Tags: javascript, jquery, linq, internet-explorer

I have a function that contains a LINQ expression, it counts how many times an element i present in the array, the function works fine in Edge, Chrome, FireFox but when ever i try to run it in Internet Explorer 10 && 11 i get a syntax error.

Is there a jquery way of doing this that will support Internet Explorer, or another work around? 
 My function:

```
 //Counts number of times the value is present in the array
  function countInArray(array, value) {
    return array.reduce((n, x) => n + (x === value), 0);
  }
```

trying to do it the way Satpal suggested caused the same error:

```
  function countInArray(array, value) {
   return array.reduce(function (n, x) { (n, x) => n + (x === value), 0 });
  }
```

the syntax error appears to be at the "=>"

Comment: Must be due to ES6 arrow function, Use `array.reduce(function(n, x){.....});`

Comment: Seeing the error would have been helpful, although Satpal's comment is most likely the correct solution

Comment: how is this related to LINQ? this is pure js

Comment: will try it out and give feedback in a sec, all the error says is "syntax error at line.." so i doubt i would have been more helpful :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right callback for getting the count is

```
function countInArray(array, value) {
    return array.reduce(function (n, x) { // equivalent to (m, x) =>
        return n + (x === value);         //               n + (x === value)
    }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not wanting to deal with the IE i made a work around.

Even though

```
return array.reduce((n, x) => n + (x === value), 0);
```

is neat, it did not work in IE so i just made it with a forloop instead

```
  function countInArray(array, value) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
      if (array[i] == value)
        count++;
    }
    return count;

  }
```